# is it possible to add new template in theme twenty seventeen?

Tags: child-theme, theme-twenty-seventeen

I have a  theme twenty-seventeen and am trying to get create new template in this theme ?? or i have create child theme of twenty seventeen .if i have to create child theme then how to convert my parent theme's pages into child theme?

Answer (score 1):

It is never a good idea to modify the theme directly, because, when the theme is updated all the modifications you made will be lost. The best course is to create a child theme, and add custom templates into the child theme, and use the child theme instead of the main one. If you need help with child themes, best way to start is here: [WordPress Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: can you please tell me i have already change my index and page files in these theme for child theme can i put my code over there ?

Comment: You can copy any template file you want from the main theme to child theme for that main theme (don't use templates from other themes, they will have different layouts, and will cause problems).